# Specify timemachine backup folder blacklist for specific backup disks

Tags: time-machine, folders

I connected two backup disks in my time machine config, one is at the office and the other one is at home. On the office drive I don't want to backup all mac, so I excluded some folder like downloads to save space, but at home I want to backup the whole mac. Is there a way to create two disk specific blacklists instead of a common one?

Comment: @mmmmmm Thanks, using carbon copy it's kinda a wa for me, I give it a try but in this way i lose time machine incremental history

Comment: In ventura and maybe earlier CCC is using snapshots like TM but agreed not the easy interface of TM but CCC does allow similar interaction